# Help with eigenvectors of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

We have the following operator

$\hat{A} = 2|u_{1}\rangle \langle u_{1}| + 2|u_{2}\rangle \langle u_{2}| + 1|u_{3}\rangle \langle u_{3}|$

with $|u_{i}\rangle $ an orthonormal base. The matrix representation of this operator is

\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

the eigenvalues are {2, 2, 1}, and the corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors are {(1 0 0), (0 1 0), (0 0 1)}

Is it possible to find a non orthonormal base of eigenvectors?

Comment: You can use Gram-Schmidt process. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: @Ramanujan you missunderstood the question

Answer (score 1):

Since any vector of the form $(a,b,0)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $2$, you can take, for instance, the basis $\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

Comment: you relied on the degenracy, right ?

Comment: @Physor I don't know what that is and therefore I cannot agree nor disagree.

Comment: I mean that for the same eigenvalue, there is at least two linearly independent vectors, so one says that the eigenvalue is degenerate, at least in quantum mechanics

Comment: @Physor I did not know the expression. Yes, I did use that.